# Conan Errror : install loop detected in context host .. requires .. which is an ancestor to

Tags: conan

I know that this might seem obvious for some of you but I've been digging everywhere for answers with no success. I'm trying to Conan install my own package from my repo but I can't get over this error. It tells me that I have a loop in my requires but my package has no requirement.

I use this recipe for upload with Conan export-pkg :

```
# Standard library imports
import configparser
import os
import sys

# Related third party imports
import conans


class TlConanFile(conans.ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "arch"

    def __init__(self, output, runner, display_name="", user=None, channel=None):  # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments
        super().__init__(output, runner, display_name, user, channel)

        if "--build-folder" in sys.argv:
            # Conan checks the arguments and fails if the value is missing, the next argument is always the value
            build_folder = sys.argv[sys.argv.index("--build-folder") + 1]
            self.__class__.exports = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(build_folder, "..", "conanfile.txt"),
                                                 os.path.dirname(__file__))

        elif "-bf" in sys.argv:
            # Conan checks the arguments and fails if the value is missing, the next argument is always the value
            build_folder = sys.argv[sys.argv.index("-bf") + 1]
            self.__class__.exports = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(build_folder, "..", "conanfile.txt"),
                                                 os.path.dirname(__file__))
        elif "-pf" in sys.argv:
            # Conan checks the arguments and fails if the value is missing, the next argument is always the value
            build_folder = sys.argv[sys.argv.index("-pf") + 1]
            self.__class__.exports = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(build_folder, "..", "conanfile.txt"),
                                                 os.path.dirname(__file__))
        elif "--package-folder" in sys.argv:
            # Conan checks the arguments and fails if the value is missing, the next argument is always the value
            build_folder = sys.argv[sys.argv.index("--package-folder") + 1]
            self.__class__.exports = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(build_folder, "..", "conanfile.txt"),
                                                 os.path.dirname(__file__))                                                 
        else:
            # Simply assume that we are running the command in the build directory
            build_folder = os.getcwd()
            self.__class__.exports = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(build_folder, "..", "conanfile.txt"),
                                                 os.path.dirname(__file__))



    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.h", dst="include/aveer", src="output/include/aveer")
        self.copy("*.i", dst="include/aveer/swig", src="output/include/aveer/swig")
        self.copy("*.so*", dst="lib", src="output/lib", symlinks=True)
        self.copy("*.cmake", dst="lib/cmake/aveer", src="output/lib/cmake/aveer")
        self.copy("*.so", dst="lib/python3/dist-packages/aveer", src="output/lib/python3/dist-packages/aveer")
        self.copy("*", dst="lib/python3/dist-packages/aveer", src="output/lib/python3/dist-packages/aveer")
        self.copy("*.yml", dst="share/gnuradio/grc/blocks", src="output/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks")
        #self.copy("*", dst="share/gnuradio/grc/blocks", src="share/gnuradio/grc/blocks") doc?

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = conans.tools.collect_libs(self)

    def requirements(self):
        with open("../conanfile.txt") as conanfile_txt:
            config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True, delimiters=["\0"])
            config.optionxform = str
            config.read_file(conanfile_txt)

            for requirement in config['requires']:
                self.requires(requirement)
```

to go with this conanfile.py, I also have this conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]

[generators]
cmake

[options]
```

that's it for the upload

and I use this conanfile.txt for the install:

```
[requires]
lib-grplugin/1.0.45@aveer_repo/Release

[generators]
cmake

[options]

[imports]
include/aveer, *.h -> ./output/include/aveer
include/aveer/swig, *.i ->./ output/include/aveer/swig
lib, *.so* -> ./output/lib
lib/cmake/aveer, *.cmake -> ./output/lib/cmake/aveer
lib/python3/dist-packages/aveer, *.so -> ./output/lib/python3/dist-packages/aveer
lib/python3/dist-packages/aveer, *.py -> ./output/lib/python3/dist-packages/aveer
share/gnuradio/grc/blocks, *.yml -> ./output/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks
```

when I try to run my conan install .. It gives me the following in the prompt:
[Picture from the command prompt with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq467.png)

I also tried to install another package to test my profile/config and it has worked as intended.

As you can see I'm new here and even newer to conan, so if you need more info that I've not mention here plz let me know.

Comment: Hi! There are some bad practices in the above code. For example, you should never implement the ``__init__`` method in your recipes. That is not part of the public, documented API, and as such is subject to breaking changes at any release, and its usage might lead to undefined behaviors. Same for ``if "--build-folder" in sys.argv:`` argv processing. I also don't understand the thing of a conanfile.txt for the upload, uploading doesn't need any conanfile.txt at all. I would recommend submitting issue to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, to discuss there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback I'll look into that